# How to show data in an expandable listView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to display the data in an expandable list view in flutter...
for instance, I need the below List as the header of the listView...
**days = ['Monday','Tuesday', 'Wednesday']**.....
and on expanding based on the day in the **days** list ....the below data gets populated of the same day.

```
List<Cars> dummyData = [
Cars(
model: 'Fiat',
speed: '100',
day: 'Monday',
),
Cars(
model: 'Maruti',
speed: '120',
day: 'Monday',
),
Cars(
model: 'Hyundai',
speed: '130',
day: 'Tuesday',
),
Cars(
model: 'Toyota',
speed: '140',
day: 'Wednesday',
),
]
```

Please let me know if you require any additional information from my end.

Comment: You need to combine more than one entry of the same day, e.g Monday has two cars so you wanna put these two cars under one header? So you need to reformat the list ?

Comment: yes I want to place the cars in their respective headers(Monday,tuesday,wednesday) ...2 cars under Monday ...1 car under Tuesday and 1 car under Wednesday and I need to display the car and their speed in the listView...can you please help me how to resolve this

Comment: I posted a suggested answer, hope it helps. You basically have to reorganize the list and put it in a Map for example and then render it placing cars in their respective headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve using expantionTile widget.

Following code may help you.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DeleteWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  List<String> _days = ['sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday'];
  List<Cars> dummyData = [
    Cars(
      model: 'Fiat',
      speed: '100',
      day: 'Monday',
    ),
    Cars(
      model: 'Maruti',
      speed: '120',
      day: 'Monday',
    ),
    Cars(
      model: 'Hyundai',
      speed: '130',
      day: 'Tuesday',
    ),
    Cars(
      model: 'Toyota',
      speed: '140',
      day: 'Wednesday',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _days.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return ExpansionTile(
                title: Text(_days[index].toString()),
                children: [
                  ...dummyData.map((e) {
                    if (e.day == _days[index]) {
                      return Text(e.speed.toString());
                    }
                    return Container();
                  }).toList(),
                ]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Cars {
  String model;
  String speed;
  String day;
  Cars({this.model, this.day, this.speed});
}
```

Comment: Hi Viren thank you so much for your help...I have tried the code and it works perfectly

Comment: Really glad to hear that it helps you. Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot Viren

Answer (score 0):

First reorganize data like the following:

```
final organizedData = new HashMap<String, List<Car>>();
for(final car in dummyData){
    if(!organizedData[car.day]){
        organizedData[car.day] = new List<Car>();
        organizedData[car.day].add(car);
    }else{
        organizedData[car.day].add(car);
    }
}
```

By doing so you will have grouped cars by each day inside a Map, for example, organizedData["Monday"] will contain the list of two cars and so on.

Now put all that in a ListView with an [expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) widget perhaps something like this:

```
  Widget expandableList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: organizedData.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        String day = organizedData.keys.elementAt(index);
        return Card(
          child: ExpandablePanel(
            header: day,
            collapsed: Text('some text', softWrap: true, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
            expanded: Card(
              child: Row(
              children: carsUI(organizedData[day]),
              ),
            tapHeaderToExpand: true,
            hasIcon: true,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  List<Widget> carsUI(List<Car> cars){
    final ui = cars.map((car){
      return Text(car.speed + ", " + car.model);
    }).toList();
    return ui;
  }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ListView.builder() widget for rendering the dynamic list and this method is an efficient method.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: dummyData.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(dummyData[index].model),
          Text(dummyData[index].day),
        ]
      ),
      trailing: Text(dummyData[index].speed)
    )
  }
)
```